# how to seperate prefixes for iptables

Tags: iptables

i hope i can ask this question here as i am bit confuse what i can and cant ask  :>
So i want to achive with iptables to seperate the prefixes in iptables example:
Connection comming first time it comes to final DROP rule and after that i have tool that analyse it and add it to different prefix and chain so it will be seperated for dropping logs if it was already once drop and added to chain.
I have this but it doesnt work the HB_LOG_AND_DROP is never showing.All the time only the last DROPLOG is shown,why?

```
$IPTABLES -N HB_LOG_AND_DROP;
$IPTABLES -A HB_LOG_AND_DROP -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES-DROPPED: " --log-level 6;
$IPTABLES -A HB_LOG_AND_DROP -j HB_LOG_AND_DROP;

$IPTABLES -N LOGPSCAN;
$IPTABLES -A LOGPSCAN -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 2000/hour -j RETURN;
$IPTABLES -A LOGPSCAN -m limit --limit 200/hour -j LOG --log-prefix "RULE PORT-SCAN [DROP] ";
$IPTABLES -A LOGPSCAN -j LOGPSCAN;
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j LOGPSCAN;

$IPTABLES -N DROPLOG;
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -j DROPLOG;
$IPTABLES -A DROPLOG -m limit --limit 1/sec -j LOG --log-prefix "[DROP] " --log-level 6;
$IPTABLES -A DROPLOG -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check
`iptables -nvL`
If the chain is above the last one. The problem was that script for automatic banning and reporting was inserting the rules with -A, when changed to -I it started to intercept fine before the last DROP.

Yeah i have been trying all possible combination for like 40times. Last is this one

```
$IPTABLES -N HB_LOG_AND_DROP;$IPTABLES -A HB_LOG_AND_DROP -m limit --limit 1/sec -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES-DROPPED: " --log-level 6;
$IPTABLES -A HB_LOG_AND_DROP -j DROP;
$IPTABLES -N LOGPSCAN;$IPTABLES -A LOGPSCAN -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 2000/hour -j RETURN;
$IPTABLES -A LOGPSCAN -m limit --limit 200/hour -j LOG --log-prefix "PORT-SCAN-DROPPED: " --log-level 6;
$IPTABLES -A LOGPSCAN -j DROP;
```

The problem was that HB_LOG_AND_DROP; was adding INPUTs from a script with -A when i change it to -I all is ok

Answer (score 0):

The following rule is incorrect:

```
$IPTABLES -A HB_LOG_AND_DROP -j HB_LOG_AND_DROP
```

This command adds a rule to `HB_LOG_AND_DROP` chain to jump into the same chain again. It causes a packet loop.

Fortunately your rules do not have any rule to jump to `HB_LOG_AND_DROP`, so you won't see the packet loop with your set of rules.

Comment: Please do not add any code or commands to comments, they are very hard to read.